# Sub-menu element under slideshow script

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, z-index

[My site](http://46.4.177.233/)

How to make orange sub-menu over JS slideshow script?

In my opinion z-index does not work correct. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to the CSS in Chrome Inspector worked for me: `#jsddm li ul { z-index: 10; }`